# Error converting from fixed array to byte pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We have an existing codebase in Unity that defines a fixed byte array (left screenshot) and then later tries to cast it to a byte pointer in an unsafe context (Test function in right screenshot). When compiling this with .NET Standard 2 API level this works exactly as expected.
Switching compatibility to .NET 4.0 on the other hand causes a compiler error stating that the FixedBuffer cannot be converted to byte*.

I know there are workarounds and different approaches, but right now I would like to understand what is causing the different behavior. Am I using incorrect syntax? Is the .NET4 specification more stringent and refuses things that were valid in older versions? Is this a Unity-only bug?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the compatibility of .NETStandard 2 with .NET Framework 4.0? I believe the earliest version of .NET Framework that is compatible .NETStandard 2 is 4.6.1.

Comment: You would typically want `fixed (byte* ptr = payload) {...}`, no? I know there is *some* support for access without `fixed` in recent c# versions, but those scenarios are fairly limited (i.e. indexers)

Comment: @MarcGravell: With that fixed (byte* ..) expression the error instead becomes: "CS2013- Cannot use fixed statement to take address of an already fixed expression."

Comment: @Cross_ oh, you're passing it in as an arg by-value? That's actually *really, really* expensive here! Pass-by-ref is absolutely recommended for structs with fixed buffers (or large structs in general) - but yes, you don't need fixed for a value known to be on the stack

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your help. It looks like this is a bug in Unity's compiler integration. Accessing the fixed buffer in the assembly where it's defined works as expected. Using the same code in a separate assembly throws errors.

Comment: @Cross_ to be fair, public fixed buffers are pretty unusual - usually they are a private implementation detail of the struct; and compiler bug or not: passing a huge struct by value is still expensive